# Why can't $.each in jquery can't read the 'data' in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, server-sent-events

I have this listener who listens in this php function

```
public function notification_query(){

$this->sse();
$data['company_id'] = $this->session->userdata('companyId');
$data['chikito']=$this->pm_model->notifications_admin($data);

echo "data: ".json_encode($data['chikito'])."\n\n";
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(1); }
```

and if the server has an event, it will pass automatically to the client side script function.

```
var es = new EventSource("<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/notification_query");

 var listener = function (data)
 {
    var data = data.data;
    //$("#notification").append(data);   
      $.each(data, function(index, val) {  
        $("#notification").append(val.details); 
       });

 }

  es.addEventListener("message", listener);
```

now the problem is, why can't the $.each in jquery can't read the data pass from the server?
It didn't print. I have no idea why.

By the way, if I use `$("#notification").append(data);` It will print the data that is pass.

thanks in advance for those who answers.

Comment: Because `data` is not an object. It's a string. `var data = $.parseJSON(data).data;` ?

Comment: now I know, thanks for the help

Comment: Can you post the sample data struct?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON.stringify() method converts a value to JSON.

```
var data = JSON.stringify(data).data;

JSON.stringify({});                  // '{}'
JSON.stringify(true);                // 'true'
JSON.stringify("foo");               // '"foo"'
JSON.stringify([1, "false", false]); // '[1,"false",false]'
JSON.stringify({ x: 5 });            // '{"x":5}'
JSON.stringify({x: 5, y: 6});        // '{"x":5,"y":6}' or '{"y":6,"x":5}'
```

Comment: maybe this will  help